# In Google Calendar with the new design, how to set default event reminder time

Tags: google-calendar, google-calendar-reminders

By default, I am now getting calendar event notifications from newly created events 10 minutes before the start time. I'd like to change this to be 5 minutes before the start time by default because otherwise I will start working on something else in that 10-minute span and forget about the meeting.

There used to be [a global setting for this in the old Google Calendar](http://www.tech-recipes.com/rx/2670/google_calendar_change_default_event_reminder/).

In the "[new Google Calendar](https://blog.google/products/g-suite/time-refresh-introducing-new-look-and-features-google-calendar-web/)", I cannot find the setting. Does it still exist? Here's what I see under settings > event settings.

[image: Google Calendar Event Settings]

The options under the "notifications" field are:

- Off
- Browser Notifications
- Interruptive Alerts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears to be a per calendar setting now.

- Click the action menu (three vertical dots) next to your calendar name in the left side bar *OR* go to `Settings` then click the calendar you want to change
- Go to `Event notifications`
- Change your default notification times

Unfortunately, it doesn't appear to be something you can change globally. A bit of a bummer for people like us who have a lot of custom and shared calendars.